# Mockup problem, can't paste my design

Tags: smartobject, mockup, photopea

I'm working with a bedsheet/bedcover mockup that I downloaded from freepik.com

I'm new in the photoshop world and I am trying to learn Photopea on my phone (android). What I know about mockup is that, the user has to double click on the "mockup-layer", then a new tab opens up and he just has to put his own design into it and click on "update smart object". And it's done!

But the mockup that I am using is a little different. Here, when I double tap on the mockup layer, no new tab opens up. But a pop-up window named "layer style" comes up. How can I paste my design here?

[image: pic 3]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 1]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Photpea may *look* like Photoshop.. but it is **not** Photoshop. I have no clue if Photopea even supports Smart Objects. You might try specifically clicking the *thumbnail* for the layer - at least that's what one would do for Photoshop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes photopea supports smart object. And I have successfully created my own designed bedsheet using mockups in Photopea. And yes I clicked on the thumbnail. But new tab didn't appear.

Comment: A guess The wanted smart object is inside the group named Fx. Expand it to see.

Comment: If this were Photoshop (which it isn't), then I would say that isn't a smart object. It looks like a regular layer with a layer mask. Smart objects in Photoshop generally have a small "document" icon on the bottom right corner of the  thumbnail to show that it's a smart object. There's no sign of that here.

Comment: And, even after expanding FX folder and other folders, I couldn't find the right "smart object layer". Here is the page link where I found this mockup                                                      https://www.freepik.com/free-psd/single-bedding-mockup-perspective_28946258.htm#query=Single%20bedding%20mockup&position=0&from_view=search

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Yes, it's not a smart object layer, so no small icon on bottom-right of the thumbnail. Now I want to know how I can reverse the "add a mask layer" step, so that I'll get two separate layers from this mask layer. Then I can turn the object layer as the smart object and then, I can try masking the two layers.

Comment: And please, could you tell me if this could be solved in Photoshop? I don't care if it's Photoshop or Photopea, I just want to know how to work with this kind of mockups, where there is no smart object layer. There are 5-6 other bed mockup in freepik.com, in which there is no smart object layer. How do people work with those mockups then?

Comment: I downloaded the file to check it in Photoshop. It contains a 3D layer, not a Smart Object. So to use this you'd likely need to use Photoshop. It's highly unlikely other other software will support a PSD containing 3D layers - this is Photoshop-only functionality.

Comment: To edit it you'd need to go into the Mattress object layers inside the 3D workspace in Photoshop and change the material.  [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/TNNIygt)

Comment: Note also that Adobe recently discontinued the 3D features in Photoshop, and these are no longer fully functional  in the most recent versions of the software. It still works in older CC versions. However, you might be better to invest time learning some proper 3D software such as Blender (which is free) for future edits like this, rather invest any time learning this in Photoshop.